# Architectural decision regarding back end

Tags: php, mysql, rest, database-design, backend

In my back end, I have a table in which I store events (activities).

After some research, I've decided to store the primary key as an auto-incremental primary key because it appears to be significantly faster than storing it as UUID.

Now in my front end, I want to create a route to show the profile of an event.
Instead of having a route like: `xyz.com/events/1`. 
I would prefer to hide the id by showing a unique string in which the event name is shown, but in a way that it forms a unique string that I can query in my database.

I've noticed that quite some websites, (incl. Facebook) are able to do this. 
They show eg. `firstname.lastname` with a number after that.

What is the best way to achieve this?
How do I generate a unique string from the event name that I can query?

Comment: You shouldn't really see any noticeable difference in speed between an autoincrementing id and a guid

Comment: @MarkBaker Thanks. I'm looking for a solution to generate a unique id based on the event name. This makes the most sense for the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In events table i would store additional unique slug (created on event save action).
f.e. "Some great event" has slug "some-great-event".
If the slug is not unique then additional distinction is needed f.e. "some-great-event-2".
You use the slug to prepare a link and as an identifier to query database record.

There are many libs to generate slugs, check github.

Comment: Thanks, generating the unique id is what my question is actually about. Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: I think the unique id (additional distinction of same slugs) don't need to be unique it must make the whole slug unique. You can: 1. use current numeric id of a record, 2. use current numeric id of a record only if generated slug is not unique (so do distinction only if it's needed) 3. Create seperate sequence/counter and use it for slugs collisions (if you dont want to pass record numeric IDs to frontend)